# What does a professional workflow creating a databse using Hibernate in Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I am not sure what's the "*modern*" way of creating a large MySQL database from scratch with Hibernate.

You would not use assembly to write a modern UI Application - that I know - so do I write `.hbm.xml` files for Hibernate by hand if I don't have to? Anyway I would prefer to use Java Annotations (e.g. `@Entity`, `@OneToMany`, etc.) before using XML but is that the level to start?

MySQL Workbench offers a quite straight forward way to create MySQL schemes, so what I do at the moment is that I create my schema in MySQL Workbench and reverse engineer it with Hibernate Tools. That way I have created my database *and* I have my annotated Java files which are hopefully correct.

But it feels strange to use MySQL Workbench to create a database for me that I reverse engineer just to have my Java files.

So you see what I am looking for is a practical way to organize my creation process that should also consider later migration processes that might be necessary.

What does an elaborate workflow for Hibernate look like?

Comment: My professional workflow is: carefully craft your database DDL by hand, in the form of FlywayDB or Liquibase migrations; carefully craft the JPA entities by hand, adding all the necessary documentation, methods, etc. Entities are the heart and soul of your application. They should just not contain getters and setters. They should be documented. Field names should be chosen carefully. Accessors should sometimes be absent, or return read-only views, etc. cascade options, lazy fetching, should also be configured with care.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi! So, writing every entity by hand is not "*2000 and late*" you'd basically recommend it here? Your argument sounds good to me. But do I need a DDL file? Can't I just write my annotated Java files? "*Entities are the heart and soul of your application.*" - I agree, I wouldn't want to mess this very fundamental thing up right at the beginning! :)

Comment: You could generate the DDL files from the entities. Bit it would still lack things like comments, tablespaces, maybe some indexes, etc. Let's assume all is perfect. You go into production with version 1.0, and users put 10 GB of data in the database. You develop version 1.1, which needs to make various changes in the schema. Do you drop the 10 GB of data and restart from scratch? That's where tools like FlywayDB and Liquibase become extremely useful.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay just to make sure I'm getting this right: 1) Craft the database by hand (in my case I am using MySQL): All entities, relations, constraints, views, etc. using FlywayDB/Liquibase 2) "*Carefully craft the JPA entities by hand*" - would that mean to translate the MySQL code into Java? 3) Document everything.

Comment: @StefanFalk keep in mind specific hibernate limitations like views and defining m-n mappings.

Comment: @Hannes Afaik Hibernate does have views and m:n mappings are not a problem as well - what exactly do you mean with *limitations*?

Comment: Haveing a n-m mapping with other attributes in the mapping table is a pain. Having an identifying primary key (where the primary key is a foreign key of another table's primary key) needs special treatment too. Views can be mapped to entities but it's really something you want to avoid. In fact the more you go into sql and understand the personality of each dbms, the less appealing hibernate gets.

Comment: @Hannes Yes indeed, m:n relations with attributes are quite hard to implement.. but what would I use to access my database once I got my DDL? Should I use Hibernate and just write every SQL statement by hand like `session.query("SELECT * FROM person");`? I really understand your arguments against Hibernate but is there at least a little bit of abstraction that Hibernate or Spring can offer? Writing every single SQL statement feels like writing assembly to me - but I don't mind doing it if it's necessary.

Comment: @JBNizet What are you using once your database is "up and running"? Are you then using Hibernate to access and modify your data (if that's even possible)?

Comment: That's the whole point of Hibernate: reading and writing data from/to a database. I don't get your question. If your question is "what do you use to migrate the database schema from version A to version B?", the answer is FlywayDB or Liquibase.

Comment: @JBNizet Well my question targets the problem that writing the DDL script does not create my Java-`@Entity`-annotated-POJOs for Hibernate. So how would I access this data? I'd again have to write all my SQL statements by hand. Is that what I want? I'm currently reading something about [EmpireDB](https://empire-db.apache.org/empiredb/hibernate.htm) which states a few negative sides of Hibernate. I'm sorry I realize my question turns out to be quite extensive but it's just such a fundamental question to me and I'm still not sure about if I already know the answer to it.

Comment: I'm not following. My first comment said: you design your DDL by hand, and you design the entities by hand. So, you have a database schema, and you have entitites, and you're thus ready to use Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: @StefanFalk spring's `JDBCTemplate`, `JOOQ`, .. If the company's policy is to use hibernate you start using `hql` a lot for reporting and aggregations.

Comment: @Hannes `JOOQ` appears to be a very good choice. I've compared now a few but from the looks of it `JOOQ` does a good job.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, sorry I didn't realize how you meant that. It sounds strange to write the database by hand and then create Java Hibernate copies. I don't think I want to use Hibernate anymore after reading a few things that speak against it - though I can't say if all of that I was reading is still true. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not the way (TM) to do it. But from 5 years of hibernate experience I start with modeling, then hand writing the DDL. I recommend against letting hibernate create your tables because hibernate cannot create indexes and decent constraints and normally you need a db init script for test, integration and production environment. Migrating this way is also easier.

When the tables are all set up I let the entities be generated by the IDE. I always get confused by the inverse relationships...

After the development is done I normally analyze the model again to add missing indices.

With hibernate you cannot define primary keys like `GENERATE ALWAYS`, constrains like `id > 0`. Hibernate will also use as default one `sequence` ant will not add `sequences` per table. The newer oracle and SQL server features are not supported.

I read once that hibernate should be used after the model is implemented but it must have been 3.x and I guess hibernate 4.x learned some new tricks.

Comment: Wow, this one strikes me. So you would not recommend to e.g. write all `@Entity` objects in Java and let Hibernate create those for me? You say "*hibernate should be used after the moddel is implemented*" would that mean that I for example reverse engineer the whole database in order to get hands on my Java files?

Comment: Eclipse has a neet plugin that analyses a database schema and generates all enities.

Comment: What's the name of the plugin?

Comment: EclipseLink plugin for jpa projects. I normally let the entities generated for eclipselink and copy them to the hibernate project. At work we use intellij a lot.

Comment: Alright! Just one more thing. You said "*I recommend against letting hibernate create your tables because*" .. my problem here is that I am not really experience with DDL - in my case MySQL - but do you know e.g. if "MySQL Workbench" can be used to replace Hibernate at the beginning? I could design my database there and create all tables first. And.. how can I use Hibernate "*after the model is implemented*"? Would that mean to "tranlate" the DDL code into Hibernate-Java code?

Comment: Mysql workbench is indeed a good starting point, helping a lot to get things right if you are just starting your db journey.